# HtmlAgilityPack HtmlWeb.Load returning empty Document

Tags: c#, html, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

I have been using HtmlAgilityPack for the last 2 months in a Web Crawler Application with no issues loading a webpage.

Now when I try to load a this particular webpage, the document OuterHtml is empty, so this test fails

```
var url = "http://www.prettygreen.com/";
var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = htmlWeb.Load(url);
var outerHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
Assert.AreNotEqual("", pageHtml);
```

I can load another page from the site with no problems, such as setting

```
url = "http://www.prettygreen.com/news/";
```

In the past I once had an issue with encodings, I played around with htmlWeb.OverrideEncoding and htmlWeb.AutoDetectEncoding with no luck.  I have no idea what could be the issue here with this webpage.

Comment: try changing your URL string to :- @"http:\\www.prettygreen.com\";

Comment: no luck, System.UriFormatException : Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems this website requires cookies to be enabled. So creating a cookie container for your web request should solve the issue:

```
var url = "http://www.prettygreen.com/";
var htmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
htmlWeb.PreRequest += request =>
    {
        request.CookieContainer = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
        return true;
    };
var htmlDoc = htmlWeb.Load(url);
var outerHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml;
Assert.AreNotEqual("", outerHtml);
```

Comment: how would you add a cookie you already have from a previous `HttpWebRequest` you already made?

Comment: @MicroR: not 100% sure, but cookies should be available within `htmlWeb` instance