# HtmlAgilityPack don't get xpath in c#

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

before, I use this code, it can get xpath of website. But, today I debug code, I see, it don't get data html from website: webtruyen.com. I try to check website.com/robots.txt. but it don't suspect. And I try to add proxy to get data, but return data null. I don't know how to get xpath from website  webtruyen.com. Who help me? I want to know how to read data from website http://webtruyen.com.

My code:

```
string url = "http://webtruyen.com";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load(url);
String temps = "";
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
{
     temps  = node.InnerHtml;
}
```

I debug, return:

- InnerHtml   'doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' string {System.NullReferenceException}

My code use proxy:

```
string url = "http://webtruyen.com";
var web = new HtmlWeb();
webGet.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) Speedy Spider (http://www.entireweb.com/about/search_tech/speedy_spider/)";
var doc = web.Load(url);
String temps = "";
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
{
     temps  = node.InnerHtml;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HtmlAgilityPack HtmlWeb.Load returning empty Document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400493/htmlagilitypack-htmlweb-load-returning-empty-document)

Comment: perhaps you need to enable cookies, see the linked question.

Comment: @Jodrell  i try to use cookies, But it dosen't get html. can you give code for my problem?

Comment: try node.Attributes["href"].Value

Comment: @SuncoastOwner Thanks. But i have error at var doc = web.Load(url); It doesn't get value for var doc. i see in debug: Id 'doc.DocumentNode.Id' threw an exception of type 'System.Exception' string {System.Exception}. U will see error: don't load load url when run this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same error using HtmlWeb.Load(), but I can easily solve your issue using HttpWebRequest (TLDR: See #3 for the working code).

Step 1) Using the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://webtruyen.com");
            using (Stream s = hwr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            { }
```

You see that you actually get a 403 Forbidden error (WebException).

Step 2)

```
        HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://webtruyen.com");
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        try
        {
            using (Stream s = hwr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            { }
        }
        catch (WebException wx)
        {
            doc.LoadHtml(new StreamReader(wx.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
        }
```

on doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml, you see the HTML of the forbidden error with the JavaScript that sets the cookie on your browser and refreshes it.

3) So in order to load the page outside of a manual browser, you have to manually set that cookie and re-access it. Meaning, with:

```
        string cookie = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://webtruyen.com");
        try
        {
            using (Stream s = hwr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
            { }
        }
        catch (WebException wx)
        {
            cookie = Regex.Match(new StreamReader(wx.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd(), "document.cookie = '(.*?)';").Groups[1].Value;
        }
        hwr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://webtruyen.com");
        hwr.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookie);
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        using (Stream s = hwr.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s))
        {
            doc.LoadHtml(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

You get the page :)

Moral of the story, if your browser can do it, so can you.

Comment: Thank you very very much. You help me for solve my problem. i hope i can knowledge as you.

Comment: No problem @toan! :) Glad to help. Now mark it as the answer.