# Why is this simple webcrawl failing?

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I am testing the HtmlAgilityPack with a very simple code snippet but it still fails and I cannot see why

```
var html2 = @"http://www.monki.com/en_sek/newin/view-all-new.html";

            HtmlWeb web2 = new HtmlWeb();

            var htmldoc2 = web2.Load(html2);

            var node2 = htmldoc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title");

            Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Node Name2: " + node2.Name + "\n" + node2.OuterHtml + "\n" + node2.InnerText);
```

I have checked of course that head and title is there on the page but still node2 is null and I cannot fogure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the web page is trying to set cookies. Also see [this answer with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13400493/htmlagilitypack-htmlweb-load-returning-empty-document)

```
var loader = new HtmlWeb{ UseCookies = true };
var doc = loader.Load(@"http://www.monki.com/en_sek/newin/view-all-new.html");

var node2 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//head/title");
Console.WriteLine("\n\n\n\n");
Console.WriteLine("Node Name2: " + node2.Name + "\n" + node2.OuterHtml + "\n" + node2.InnerText);
```